# Logon error accessing SQL Server 2012 Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, desktop-application

I developed a windows form application (Visual Studio 2019) to "manage" my uncle's clinic. Matter of fact, this program does 2 things: registers clients and has an agenda in which you can schedule the visits (and everything is stored in SQL Server tables).

My problem is: After installing my program in his computer(which I previously installed SQL Server 2012 Express and the PC runs on windows 10), I always get a logon error when the program is launched. The installation method was the simplest I sent him the installation file.

What I did: created the database (with SSMS) inside my local server, which allows SQL Server and Windows authentication. Created a setup project in visual studio to make an installation package. Then, as I always got that error, I tried different connection strings, but without success.

```
@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=C:\Program Files (x86)\Gestor\FisioGest\fisiodb.mdf; Integrated Security=SSPI"

@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Database=fisiodb.mdf; Integrated Security=SSPI"

@"Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Database= fisiodb.mdf; User ID=xxxxx; Password = xxxxx"
```

(here the user id and password were from the SQL Server authentication).

I have no idea what parts I'm missing... Do I have to set his server to allow Windows and SQL Server authentication as well?

Comment: Have you copied the database to his machine and attached or restored it on his local SQL Server?

Comment: Actually I think my answer would be none of these. Because I thought that using the package installation (which installs the database to that directory (see first con. string)), I would have no problems regarding to "is it even there?". Thanks a lot for your prompt reply.

Comment: I checked, and the database is in fact in that directory as it was supposed to be. I forgot to tell that the 2 con. string gives me an error from the user of his computer to logon, and the third con. string gives me error from the sql authentication user to logon. Seems like a paradox. Should I be giving permissions to the database file directly?

Comment: You wrote an entire question without reproducing the error. What was the error?

Comment: The errors i get are logon errors, like this: "it wasn't possible to open the database "fisiodb.mdf" asked by the logon. Fail of logon. fail to logon with the user .... ". If I use the 2nd con. string the user name is of his computer, if I use the 3rd con. string the user is the same name as from my SQL Server authentication user id.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server will not attach a datbase file unless you tell it to with the AttachDbFileName connectinon string parameter. EG

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\DatabaseFileName.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj653752(v=vs.110)

Alternatively you can [attach the database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-ver15) as part of your setup process.

Comment: I tried this string and the error was: "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network interfaces, error:26 - Error locating server/instance specified)"